# Regexp return true, but author of a book says it shouldn't

Tags: php, regex

Reading an online resource on PHP about Regexp(TuxRadar).
According to the author the following should not match "aaa1" to the pattern and therefore return false(0), but I get true(1).

```
<?php

$str = "aaa1";
print preg_match("/[a-z]+[0-9]?[a-z]{1}/", $str);

?>
```

Why?

[Regular Expressions](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/8/3)

Comment: There's no final alpha char at the end of the string, so the author's right. Try assigning the pre_match to a var, then var_dump'ing it.

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher - You are incorrect. Give it a go!

Comment: @Ed you're right, and I see why now :)

Comment: the above regex matches "aaa" in the string "aaa1" and returns true(1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure there isn't supposed to be a trailing `$` there? Without it, returning true makes a lot of sense - the first `[a-z]` block matches the first 2 `a` characters, the `[0-9]` matches nothing, and the last `[a-z]` matches the 3rd `a`. The trailing `1` is ignored.

Looking at the link to the book, it does seem there's an error there:

> Must end with a lower case letter

This is only true if the regular expression is anchored to the end of the string with a `$`.

Comment: Why is 1 ignored? It is optional, I get it. But he does supply it. Shouldn't the expression then be finished with "aaa1a" to match it?

Comment: Well, the way the RE engine works, it would *try* that first, matching all 3 `a` characters, but then it would indeed fail to match. At that point, the engine will *backtrack*, removing one of the `a` matches, and try again from that point. Only then, since the `[0-9]` is optional, would the match succeed.

Comment: Very confusing I have to say. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It matches because `[0-9]?` matches a digit **zero** or one times.

```
<?php
$str = "aaa1";
print preg_match("/[a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z]{1}/", $str);
?>
```

won't result in a match.

Comment: I agree, but he does supply a 1.

Comment: Yes, but `[0-9]?` will match a digit either zero or one times.  Since `[a-z]+[0-9]?[a-z]{1}` matches one or more (lower case) letters followed by an optional digit followed by one more character, the string `"aaa1"` matches since matching the digit is optional.  And incidentally, the `{1}` is superfluous: `[a-z]+[0-9]?[a-z]{1}` is the same as `[a-z]+[0-9]?[a-z]`.

Comment: So, the author made a mistake?

Comment: If the author claimed that `/[a-z]+[0-9]?[a-z]{1}/` doesn't match the string `"aaa1"`, then yes.

Comment: Since you know who this author is and the rest of us don't, you might want to inform him/her.

Answer (score 2):

Lets break down the regular expression

1. [a-z]+ means one or more letters, being gready that would match a, aa or aaa
2. [0-9]? means an optional - so could match a digit
3. [a-z] means to match a letter, that could be an a

Therefore due to the [0-9] being optional 1 would match aa, 2 would match nothing and 3 would match an a

Comment: Then what is the point of having a `[0-9]?` part? Does the regexp just ignores it?

Comment: @Bob the `?` means "match 0 or 1 of the previous". meaning that `[0-9]?` would return true if no number was in the string because "0" of the previous numbers were matched. The point of having `[0-9]?` is that if there were two or more numbers, it could fail depending on the regex.